# Como limitar o uso de uma aplicação web para que possa ser usada apanas pelo Chrome?

Tags: java, aplicação-web, google-chrome, navegador-de-internet, genexus

Minha aplicação é baseada em Java e feita em Genexus.

Quero que seja impossível usar minha aplicação fora do Google Chrome.

Tem como implementar essa limitação?

Não encontrei em minhas pesquisas esse conteúdo em específico, gostaria da ajuda da comunidade.

Muito obrigado!

Comment: Esse é uma pergunta um tanto... inusitada. Porque limitar ao Chrome?

Comment: Em outros navegadores podem existir conflitos com os estilos e a responsividade do site.

Comment: E não é melhor adaptar o css para ser cross-browser?

Comment: Sugiro que concerte seu CSS, principalmente se o estilo atrapalha a usabilidade em outros browsers. Pense que horrível acessar o seu site pelo firefox e receber uma mensagem 'Browser Errado!', ou pior...

Comment: A mensagem seria mais amigável... "Por favor utilize o Chrome.", ahahahahaha. Mas suas sugestões são boas pois por já estar no ambiente web, a aplicação deveria ser multiplataforma

Answer (score 1):

Tayrone,

Há uma função que é BrowserID para identificar o navegador. Com isso, no "ponto de entrada" da sua aplicação poderia identificar o navegador e se não for Chrome dar uma mensagem e não executar o aplicativo. 
Mais informações sobre a função: http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?8336,BrowserId%20function

Gustavo

Comment: Esse é justo o caso que eu gostaria de implementar na aplicação.

Muito obrigado, Gustavo. Vou estudar essa função e tentar colocar em prática!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer usando o BrowserID como Gustavo sugeriu.
Mas se você quer fazer essa limitação para evitar bugs inesperados por falta de suporte para um ou mais recursos, recomendo utilizar uma biblioteca como modernizr (https://modernizr.com). Limitar uma aplicação à funcionar só em um browser não é errado, apenas desaconselhável.

Comment: a Modernizr detecta e informa problemas nos recursos para que então, consciente desses problemas, eu possa resolve-los? Ela sugere resoluções também?

Comment: `Modernizr é uma pequena biblioteca Javascript que detecta a disponibilidade das novas características do HTML5 e CSS3 nos browsers. Muitas destas características já estão implementadas nos browsers, mas é muito chato você decorar quais novidades os browsers já estão suportando. O que a Modernizr faz é simples: ela te diz quais features um determinado browser suporta e insere classes no HTML para que você possa utilizar para fazer uma versão alternativa de visual ou solução.`

Comment: Tentei escrever em uma só resposta mas enviei sem querer. Dá uma lida nesse artigo do Tableless, acho que tira a maioria das suas dúvidas:

Comment: http://tableless.com.br/utilizando-a-biblioteca-modernizr/